# Calling stat from <sys/stat.h> faills with "Value too large for defined data type" error

Tags: c, posix, runtime-error, system-calls

Given tmp.c:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(argv[1], &st) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error calling stat");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get `Error calling stat: Value too large for defined data type`, when I run the program on a large file (~2.5 Gb).

Comment: This (`EOVERFLOW`) shall only happend on 32bit systems if the file's size exceeds `(2<<31)-1` bits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One needs to `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64`: either add it before you 
`#include <sys/stat.h>` or define it in your platform-specific way e.g., for gcc see -D option; for Visual Studio go to project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions

Comment: This really help! I encountered this when i stat files on SD more than 2GB. It gives me 'Value too large...' error message. Now i can stat them on my Android device.

Comment: That solution didn't work for me. I add option to "Preprocessor Definition" (VS 2019), but that didn't help

Answer (score 3):

If others have this problem and the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` before `#include "sys/stat.h"` did not solve it yet, just move it in front of all other include's too. I did not find out which headers also depended on this but it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, you've just helped me fix a bug!

Comment: The selected answer did not work for me.  But this one did, ty!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in to this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type) . It provides you the way to handle such issue.

This is typically done by defining -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 or some such. It is system dependent. Once done and once switched into this new mode most programs will support large files just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are able to remove this limitation by including header file **config.h** in your program.
and this is not necessary to include whole file but you are also able to put one macro #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64 to remove limitation.